# Unable to install any software or access kuser

Tags: linux, rhel

I've just installed RHEL 7.6. I've installed Base environment: Server with GUI with all addons for selectred environment

During Installation I created Root Password & created user from User Creation with, Make this user administrator option

Now, post install & after successful login to RHEL environment, I'm unable to install any software or access KUser to edit user permission or change user group

While installing anything it gives error something went wrong, Error msg when trying to use KUser , Error opening /etc/shadow for reading

How to give root permissions to user created during Installation?

Answer (score 0):

The part of your question about root access is quite straightforward. The user account configured with the 'Make this user administrator' checkbox during installation is added to a special group named 'wheel'. Members of the 'wheel' group can use `sudo` to execute commands requiring root privileges. As an example, if you want to add a user with the `useradd` command, you would run it as `sudo useradd [options] [username]` from your administrator account.

Your question also mentions an application named KUser. [KUser](https://kde.org/applications/unmaintained/kuser) appears to be a now un-maintained component associated with the KDE Desktop. The default desktop environment used on RHEL 7 is GNOME 3. On the GNOME desktop environment, you can use the [User Administration Tool](https://help.gnome.org/users/users-admin/stable/tool-getting-started.html.en) to add/modify/delete users and groups. The User Administration tool should be available from the GUI at 'Administration' > 'Users and groups'. From the command line, it can be accessed with the command `users-admin`.